# C++ -- Column Formatting

Tags: c++, arrays, formatting, output

I have been struggling with this the past several hours, but I need help formatting some output. Basically, I have a two-dimensional array `arr` that I want to be printed in 3 X 70 groups, i.e.

```
aaaaaa ... a //Columns 1-70
bbbbbb ... b //Columns 1-70
cccccc ... c //Columns 1-70
             //newline
             //newline
             //newline
aaaaaa ... a //Columns 1-70
bbbbbb ... b //Columns 1-70
cccccc ... c //Columns 1-70

//and so on like that until all of top, mid, and bot is printed out
```

where `aaaa....a` corresponds to `arr[0]`, `bbbbb....b` corresponds to `arr[1]`, and `cccc...c` corresponds to `arr[2]`.

Another part is that `arr` corresponds to three one-dimensional arrays `top`, `mid`, and `bot`. As you can probably guess, `aaaa...aaa` are the values in `top`, `bbbb...bbb` are the values in `mid`, and `ccc....ccc` are the values in `bot`. The lengths of `top`, `mid`, and `bot` are all the same, thus one field `length` has been assigned to that value.

My current code is (excluding the imports):

```
string alignToString;
stringstream out;

char arr[3][70];


for (int column = 1; column <= length; ++column)
{
    out << top[column - 1];
    if (column % 70 == 0)
    {
        out << endl;
        for (int column = 1; column < 70; ++column)
        {

        }
    }

    arr[0][column] = top[column - 1];
    arr[1][column] = mid[column - 1];
    arr[2][column] = bot[column - 1];

    if (column % 70 == 0)
    {
        break;
    }

//TODO: output out.str();
}
```

This code does not work, obviously. I had the idea that maybe I could output each column in groups of three and once column % 70 = 0, I'd add the newlines, but I can't seem to figure that out. If anyone can help me out with this problem, or provide a better solution to this problem, I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I have not clue what the role of top,mid,bot is. Actually I can't understand what you are trying to do. Also you did not write what the current output is and in which way it is different from what you want. If you really want to get an answer you should rewrite you question.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little unclear - what is `arr` used for? Do you actually want to copy each row from `top`, `mid` and `bot` into `arr` for later use, as well as printing? Or was it just part of your attempted solution? If you don't need it for other purposes, then there's no benefit in copying the data out of the three arrays with your data into these temporary buffers.

The other bit that's not obvious is whether you want an in memory string representation, or to actually print directly to `cout`. If the latter, then again there's no real benefit in temporarily writing to a `stringstream` buffer beforehand - the characters will be written in the same order either way.

I've assumed that you intended both, but if not the solution can be made to run faster. Speaking of speed, though compilers are getting better at optimising it, working character by character can be very slow. Using [std::ostream::write()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/write/) to take long runs of characters at a time is clearer and faster.

```
const size_t maxColumn = 70;

char arr[3][maxColumn];

using CharIteratorPair = std::pair<char *, char *>;

CharIteratorPair myArrays[] = {
    { top, arr[0] },
    { mid, arr[1] },
    { bot, arr[2] }};

std::stringstream out;

for (size_t i = 0 ; i < length; i += maxColumn) {
    size_t gulpSize = std::min(maxColumn, length - i);

    for (auto& source: myArrays) {
        out.write(source.first, gulpSize);
        out << std::endl;

        // Remove this line if you don't need to copy the data
        // into "arr"
        std::copy_n(source.first, gulpSize, source.second);

        std::advance(source.first, gulpSize);
    }   

    // "arr" has now been filled in, do other processing here for each
    // group of three rows as needed
}   

// out has now been filled in, ready for extracting with .str()
// or printing to std::cout etc.

std::cout << out.str();
```